# I have made a dictionary using a list as the values for each key, I want to print the values without square brackets

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
new_items = {'bacon': items, 'bread': items, 'cheese': items}
for key, value in new_items.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, *value))
```

Output:

```
bacon: Item 1
bread: Item 1
cheese: Item 1
```

How do I get all of the items to print? If I remove the asterisk before `value` it prints all 3 items, but in square brackets.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the string to be output right in the `format()` method call:

```
items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
new_items = {'bacon': items, 'bread': items, 'cheese': items}
for key, values in new_items.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, ', '.join(values)))
```

Output:

```
bacon: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
bread: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
cheese: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The question reduces to "how to convert a list to a string?".  Some possible options which might suit you:

```py
In [1]: items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']

In [2]: ' '.join(items)
Out[2]: 'Item 1 Item 2 Item 3'

In [3]: ', '.join(items)
Out[3]: 'Item 1, Item 2, Item 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in how you construct `new_items`. Try this instead, then print:

```
items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
labels = ['bacon', 'bread', 'cheese'}
new_items = zip(labels, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
new_items = {'bacon': items, 'bread': items, 'cheese': items}
for key, value in new_items.items():
    print(f'{key}: {", ".join(value)}')
```

Output:

```
bacon: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
bread: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
cheese: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
```